# Trying to achieve function overloading in C based on number of arguments, not types

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to do some sort of object oriented programming in C. One of the things I'm stuck at is how to get an overload of a function based on the number of arguments passed. I can't see why, but when I pass 3 parameters, contructor1 gets called.

**EDIT:** added includes and the struct definition, so the code now is compilable.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct my_type_struct my_type;

void constructor1 ( my_type * object, uint16_t arg1 );
void constructor2 ( my_type * object, uint16_t arg1, uint16_t arg2 );
void constructor3 ( my_type * object, const void * const array_arg1, 
    uint16_t arg2, uint16_t arg3 );

#define GET_CONTRUCTOR_OVERLOAD(_1, _2, _3, NAME, ...) NAME
#define INIT_OBJECT(...) GET_CONTRUCTOR_OVERLOAD(__VA_ARGS__, \
    constructor3, constructor2, constructor1)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCTOR(name, ...) my_type name; INIT_OBJECT(&name, __VA_ARGS__)

struct my_type_struct
{
    int field;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[30];
    CONSTRUCTOR(obj, a, sizeof(int), 30);//invokes constructor1
}

void constructor1 ( my_type * object, uint16_t arg1 )
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    object->field = 1;
}
void constructor2 ( my_type * object, uint16_t arg1, uint16_t arg2 )
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    object->field = 2;
}
void constructor3 ( my_type * object, const void * const array_arg1, 
uint16_t arg2, uint16_t arg3 )
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    object->field = 3;
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this properly?

Comment: This smells lile an X/Y problem to me. Is there a legitimate reason for doing this? Is it more readable than making the call directly? Is it more maintainable than using a language that supports this out of the box?

Comment: This looks like a debugging nightmare. This is even worse as you also inhibit type checking from the compiler. Clear advice: **Don't**. Function name overloading by different parameters is not required for OOP and not supported by all (true) OOP languages either.

Comment: @Olaf it's supported by all OOP languages I know (Java, C++ and C#). Not sure if they are true OOP languages though, because I'm an amateur and I have no formal education in Computer Science. Just love coding.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: You should learn more then. N. Wirth e.g. refused using paramter-based function overloading as too confusing for Oberon. Python as a true high-level OOPL (Neither of C++, C# nor Javea are OOP to that extend) does not support it either. The term "OOP" includes various features. There is no well-defined set of features to be supported by a language making it "OOP". Even inheritance is not necessarily required. You can e.g. use component-based OOP. Anyway, Don't try to do this in C; some reason I already gave.

Comment: @Olaf well, it's more like an experiment. As you said, I should learn more. It helps understanding OOP better if I can make "my own".

Comment: @FinnTheHuman: How does fiddling with C macros help understand OOP? Better read about compiler construction and how to do it for an OOP compiler. E.g. N. Wirth "compiler construction" is available for free download and shows very well the basics. Anyway, be happy, I just hope I will never have to rework such code. Had enough macro-magic to fix in the past already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  GET_CONTRUCTOR_OVERLOAD, so it will be able to handle 4 arguments and select the correct function:

```
#define GET_CONTRUCTOR_OVERLOAD(_1, _2, _3, _4, NAME, ...) NAME
```

See it in action here: https://ideone.com/5Iobu1

Comment: if I do that, no constructor is called at all.

Comment: constructor1 was called.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman No, constructor3 was called. Did you even visit the link?

Comment: that's weird! constructor1 gets called here at my computer!

Comment: @FinnTheHuman So if you copy paste the code in the above ideone link into a new file and compile and run it, the result is? And which compiler are you using?

Comment: I get nothing. (didn't notice you had added the _4 to the macro, so I was running my version which ends at _3). I get a runtime warning 

C4003 not enough actual parameters for macro 'GET_CONTRUCTOR_OVERLOAD'

and no constructor is called. Oh and I'm using VisualStudio2015. So I'm guessing the default compiler for that

Comment: @FinnTheHuman You're not using a compliant C compiler. Use gcc.

Comment: @2501: Do you mean gcc with standard C or with extensions? I see trouble if there are no arguments at all.

Comment: @Olaf Just a normal C compiler. This macro should work so, either OP or VS is doing something wrong.

Comment: @2501: as I don't use VS. But you should include the code in your answer to make it complete. What if ideone goes offline? Anyway, I think this is a terrible approach OP follows. Too much macro-magic is more confusing than doing good.

Comment: @Olaf The code is in the question. My answer is correct without the link. Only the `_4` must be added and that is it.

Comment: I know the code breaks with no arguments. That's no problem for me. I don't know how to tell visual studio to use a different compiler

Comment: @Olaf I agree that this shouldn't be used in real code.